# Why is my kick command not working? Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
@client.command.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await member.kick()
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(" ")
    await ctx.send(f"{member.name} has been kicked by {ctx.author.name}!")
    await log_channel.send(f"{ctx.author.name} has kicked {member.display_name}")
```

And I am getting this error

@client.command.has_permissions(administrator=True)

True unticpeted intent

Answer (score 0):

It's not `@client.command.has_permissions()`, It's `@commands.has_permissions()` and make sure you have `from discord.ext import commands` imported

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await member.kick()
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(" ")
    await ctx.send(f"{member.name} has been kicked by {ctx.author.name}!")
    await ctx.log_channel.send(f"{ctx.author.name} has kicked {member.display_name}")
```